# Multiple div carousel functionality using HTML/CSS/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, carousel

How to achieve the carousel of multiple divs after clicking on add button? For each loop will repeat the div for every click of Add button. After click, multiple divs to be placed side by side and when it is overflow we need to do the carousel functionality for it with arrow marks as next and prev. Any Ideas on how to solve this?

```css
.small-header {
        min-height: 124px;
        background-position: center right;
        text-align: center;
        display: table;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 22px 20px 0;
        background: #fff;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    .small-header .vertical-align {
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
    .component-carousel {
        width: 530px;
        display: block;
        margin: 0 auto;
        position: relative;
        margin-bottom: 40px;
    }
    .component-carousel:before {
        left: 0;
    }
    .component-carousel:after, .component-carousel:before {
        content: "";
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        width: 20%;
        height: 100%;
        z-index: 1;
    }
    .component-carousel .outer-content {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .component-carousel .items {
        position: relative;
        height: 190px;
        left: 145px;
    }
    .component-carousel .items .item {
        top: 0;
        left: -50px;
        height: 190px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        float: left;
        margin: 0 20px 0 0;
        position: relative;
        display: table;
    }

    .your {
        display: block;
        height: 290px;
        border: 2px solid #5e6a71;
        text-align: center;
        font-weight: 600;
        letter-spacing: 1px;
        padding: 15px 0 0 0;
        width: 244px;
        position: relative;
        background: #fff;
    }
    .component-carousel .bullets {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: -25px;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        z-index: 3;
    }
    .component-carousel .bullets li {
        transition: all .15s ease-out;
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 0 3px;
    }
    .your>p.card-number {
        margin-top: 95px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        position: relative;
        color: #5e6a71;
    }
    .your .infonumber {
        display: block;
    }
    .your p.card-number:after {
        content: "";
        display: block;
        width: 70%;
        height: 1px;
        background: #bec3c6;
        margin: 0 auto;
        margin-top: 7px;
    }
    .card-left:after {
        content: "";
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        width: 1px;
        height: 95px;
        background: #cecfd1;
        right: -15px;
        top: 0;
    }
    .card-detail-container {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 80px;
        left: 0;
        top: 180px;
        color: #5e6a71;
    }
    .card-left {
        display: block;
        float: left;
        width: 50%;
        position: relative;
        padding:0 18px;
    }
    .card-right {
        display: block;
        float: left;
        width: 50%;
        position: relative;
        padding:0 35px;
    }
    .card-detail-container p {
        line-height: 14px !important;
    }

    .component-carousel.show-two .controls {
        display: none;
    }
    .component-carousel .controls {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        z-index: 2;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
    }
    .component-carousel .controls li.disabled {
        opacity: .2;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .component-carousel .controls li:first-child {
        left: 0;
    }

    .component-carousel .controls li {
        transition: all .15s ease-out;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        cursor: pointer;
        background: url(/image/component/carousel/arrows.png) no-repeat center left;
        height: 100%;
        width: 19px;
    }
    .component-carousel .controls li:last-child {
        right: 0;
        background-position: center right;
    }
    .button {
        border: 1px solid #a8a8a8;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-weight: 600;
        background: #FFFFFF;
        position: relative;
        text-decoration: none;
        white-space: normal;
        cursor: pointer;
        color: #292929;
    }
    .btn {
        position: relative;
        color: #4f4f4f;
        left: 38%;
        width: 25% !important;
        max-width: 580px;
        text-transform: capitalize;
    }
```

```html
@using (Html.BeginForm("", "", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal" }))
      {
        if (Model.Details != null && Model.Details.Count() > 0)
        {
            <div class="small-header">
            <div class="vertical-align">
            <div class="component-carousel">
            <div class="outer-content">
            <div class="mask">
            <ul class="items" style="transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);">
               <li class="item">
                 @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                  <div class="your">                                       
                    <p class="card-number">
                      <span class="infonumber">123456</span>                                      
                    </p>                
                  <div class="card-detail-container">
                    <div class="card-left">
                      <p class="card-shape-title">Circle</p>
                      <p class="card-barcode-title">24242</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-right">
                      <p class="card-carat-title">222</p>
                      <p class="card-certificate-title"></p>
                    </div>
                 </div>               
               </div>           
               }
            </li>
          </ul>
         </div>
        </div>
        <ul class="controls">
          <li class="prev disabled"></li>
          <li class="next"></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
   </div>
 }
 <div class="btns">
     <button type="submit" id="addinfo" class="btn button" value="Add">Add<span></span><span></span></button>
 </div>
}
```

Comment: Guys, it's very urgent for me to finish this functionality, Can anyone please respond???